# Exclude "undefined" results in for loop on JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Currently all results are returned however when no _miner is found, it returns undefined in the console and continues showing time and blocks. How can I have no output made when no _miner is returned?

The output should be something like this, where time "3" had no _miner match so nothing was output for it.

```
1
123
10
2
124
10
4
123
10
```

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/api/payments",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    var _miner = "t1XHpNtYY2N3EMDRoX9RM2hq4DWWPZSmawJ";

    var addr = _miner;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      //Name
      console.log(data[i].name);

      var payments = data[i].payments;
      for (var j = 0; j < payments.length; j++) {

        //Time
        console.log(payments[j].time);

        //blocks
        var blocks = payments[j].blocks;
        for (var b = 0; b < blocks.length; b++) {
          console.log(blocks[b])
        }

        console.log(payments[j].amounts[_miner]);


      }
    }

  },
  error: function() {
    //alert("Was unable to get info!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you do not want the for loop to execute if _miner is empty?

Comment: I would just check if the value is undefined prior to logging. !== undefined works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check if it exists:

```
if (payments[j].amounts[_miner] === undefined)
    console.log(payments[j].amounts[_miner]);
```

or better still:

```
if (payments[j].amounts[_miner] === undefined) 
   console.log(payments[j].amounts[_miner]) 
else
   console.log("no payments")
```

or even:

```
console.log((payments[j].amounts[_miner] === undefined) ? payments[j].amounts[_miner] : "no payments");
```

Comment: Of course this would negate all `0` values, if there is any payment that resolves to `0`

Comment: @vol7ron you are correct. Improved the code based on your comment. Thanks.

Comment: It may not matter since the app may not allow 0 value transactions, but this looks like crypto so it’s not a traditional payment system and really low value transactions may be possible :)